# how can i use special characters including operands in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Im having problems with special characters in sql query. I tried escaping using {} , mysqli_escape , but it doesnt work.

My query looks like this....

```
("SELECT  * FROM cars WHERE  car_id= '$carid' AND car_des='$car_des' AND engine= 'B' "); 

$carid = 123;
$car_des = Toyota <'kk'>;
```

so my query reads as follows

```
("SELECT  * FROM cars WHERE  car_id= '123' AND car_des='Toyota <'kk'>' AND engine= 'B' ");
```

Comment: Escape; or better yet, learn to use prepared statements with bind variables

Comment: Refer to the linked answer for the proper solution

Comment: Back slash the single quotes

Comment: ("SELECT  * FROM cars WHERE  car_id= '123' AND car_des='Toyota <\'kk\'>' AND engine= 'B' ");

Comment: i cant just backslash remember is a declared variable. its not all variables that are going to be like that

Comment: i have a solution .. i just str_replace " <' "  with " <\' "